# In C, how is a data member of a struct used as part of a function pointed to by a member of the same struct?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I have two forward declared functions and a struct:

```
int _bar(void*);
int _bar2(int);

typedef struct foo {
  void* array[128];
  int (*bar)(void* x) = _bar;
  int (*bar2)(int x) = _bar2;
} FOO;
```

How can `array` be accessed from `bar` and `bar2` in an arbitrary instance of `FOO`, such that `array` is mutable by each function? **Can it be done?**

And yes, I know it's easier and arguably better to just use something other than C to do this kind of thing. That's simply not the point, so *please* answer the question *as asked*, without an attempt to 'diagnose' some deeper problem like many replies here do.

Comment: also usually in `C` all uppercase identifiers are used for macros, so don't use `FOO` for a struct.

Comment: Asserting that your question is not an XY problem? Hmm.

Comment: Note that the syntax used in the `typedef` with the `=` signs is not valid C syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to do OOP in `C`. You want `bar` and `foo` to be like C++ member function. You can't do that in `C` and you should't even try. Don't fight the language.

Just add a `Foo` parameter to the free functions:

```
typedef struct foo {
  void* array[128];
} Foo;

int bar(/*const*/ Foo* foo, void*);
int bar2(/*const*/ Foo* foo, int);
```

Comment: The `Foo*` parameter is essentially what a C++ compiler does behind the scenes anyway (to pass the `this` pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo {
  int array[128];
  int(*bar)(struct foo* this, void* x);
  int(*bar2)(struct foo* this, int x);
} FOO;


int _bar(FOO *this, void *p)
{
  printf("bar2(%p)\n", p);
  return 0;
}

int _bar2(FOO *this, int i)
{
  printf("array[4] = %d\n", this->array[4]);
  printf("bar2(%d)\n", i);
  return i*2;
}

void ConstructFoo(struct foo *f)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(f->array) / sizeof(f->array[0]); i++)
    f->array[i] = i;

  f->bar = _bar;
  f->bar2 = _bar2;
}

int main()
{
  struct foo f;
  ConstructFoo(&f);

  printf ("%d\n", f.bar2(&f, 42));
}
```

I modified the type of `array` just for makeing the example simpler.

This example can be enhanced further depending on what you actually need, for example you could add function that set the `bar` and `bar2` "member" functions to something else than `_bar` and `_bar2`.

Comment: why not just `bar2(&f, 42)` instead of `f.bar2(&f, 42)`. I see no point in this. It's an added complexity with 0 benefits, just because it remotely resembles how an OOP code would look. I know technically that's what the OP asked for, but I think it's our responsibility to point out when what the OP wants to do is not feasible.

Comment: With `f.bar2(&f, 42)` it is easier to implement inheritance. Specially function override.